# How to get the Time in HH:MM AM PM format IN eloquent from SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, laravel, eloquent

In SQL Server there is a datetime field. Dont care about date and concerned about time portion. while insert it goes as 9:30 AM, 11:30 PM like that. When I retrieved back I use **eloquent ORM** find method which is returning as

> 1900-01-01 09:30:00.000

I just want to retrieve the data in the same format from the eloquent approach e.g. 9:30 AM

P.S : SQL Query which gives the proper format (but I need it in Eloquent way)

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(RIGHT('0'+LTRIM(RIGHT(CONVERT(varchar,endTime,100),7)),7),'AM',' AM'),'PM',' PM')
FROM servers 
WHERE serverid = 12
```

Result as 9:30 AM

Comment: Can some one explain why its got negative mark. I believe its a valid question, where as no one has come across till now.

Comment: if 2012+ you can use Format(endTime,'h:mm tt')   use hh if you want 09:30

Comment: you shouldn't be doing this in the `select` query, this is something that should be done in the presentation layer. Also, if you don't care about the date, why are you storing it in a `datetime`? use a different data type to avoid this issue.

Comment: Thank you Tanner. It would be done in presentation layer. Just a curiosity of learning Eloquent ORM asked here.

Answer (score 0):

You should have defined your column as a date in your model:

```php
protected $dates = [
    'end_time',
];
```

This will "cast" the attribute value to a [Carbon](http://carbon.nesbot.com/) instance, on which you can format the date time:

```php
$model->end_time->format('g:i A');
```

Comment: defined in model just below the other variable.                                      public $timestamps = false;    
protected $dates = [
        'end_time',
    ];
 When I access the same in controller, getting some error "Call to a member function format() on null"
 $server = Servers::find($id);
 echo $server->end_time->format('g:i A');

Comment: Is your database column/attribute _actually_ `end_time`? As I just used that as an example/placeholder.

Comment: Column name is endTime

Comment: Then use that instead of `end_time`. Although it would be better to stick with Laravel conventions (snake_case) for table and column names if you’re wanting to use Eloquent.